# Access statements of Wikidata entities by id

Tags: sparql, wikidata, linked-data, wikidata-api

I would like to know if there's a way to find a Wikidata entity by specified property using their API.

This is my request:
https://www.wikidata.org/w/api.php?action=wbgetclaims&format=json&entity=Q85670252

Output results:

```
{"entities":{"Q85670252":{"pageid":84947212,"ns":0,"title":"Q85670252","lastrevid":1176468591,"modified":"2020-05-08T09:30:35Z","type":"item","id":"Q85670252","labels":{"en":{"language":"en","value":"V* DE Ara"},"ru":{"language":"ru","value":"DE \u0416\u0435\u0440\u0442\u0432\u0435\u043d\u043d\u0438\u043a\u0430"}},"descriptions":{},"aliases":{},"claims":{"P881":[{"mainsnak":{"snaktype":"value","property":"P881","hash":"040f911a2b003c74eca26e2c754be1543a8d2375","datavalue":{"value":{"entity-type":"item","numeric-id":744691,"id":"Q744691"},"type":"wikibase-entityid"},"datatype":"wikibase-item"},"type":"statement","id":"Q85670252$505550EC-917A-4BD7-AF76-725CD6BE665E","rank":"deprecated","references":[{"hash":"70cd5867f06ff077d4f8b588b777cc3836b636a3","snaks":{"P248":[{"snaktype":"value","property":"P248","hash":"d767c737627dd387e3a174287369ffa08cb014f1","datavalue":{"value":{"entity-type":"item","numeric-id":66617197,"id":"Q66617197"},"type":"wikibase-entityid"},"datatype":"wikibase-item"}]},"snaks-order":["P248"]}]},{"mainsnak":{"snaktype":"value","property":"P881","hash":"c1067020dc73cb1115360e0baf043a88f3b86d2c","datavalue":{"value":{"entity-type":"item","numeric-id":1153690,"id":"Q1153690"},"type":"wikibase-entityid"},"datatype":"wikibase-item"},"type":"statement","id":"Q85670252$491B889B-99D8-4653-B296-F412D94AAAA5","rank":"normal","references":[{"hash":"221380bbe3481a43235282a275b47ec60cf42e03","snaks":{"P248":[{"snaktype":"value","property":"P248","hash":"426249303a30c5c40946d21d957f6c7c88ef97e3","datavalue":{"value":{"entity-type":"item","numeric-id":66649410,"id":"Q66649410"},"type":"wikibase-entityid"},"datatype":"wikibase-item"}]},"snaks-order":["P248"]}]}],"P6879":[{"mainsnak":{"snaktype":"value","property":"P6879","hash":"62e93b9f3ae3a8a4e5aacdcfd4358becabb9107a","datavalue":{"value":{"amount":"+3200","unit":"http://www.wikidata.org/entity/Q11579"},"type":"quantity"},"datatype":"quantity"},"type":"statement","id":"Q85670252$1A59C312-475C-426D-B818-CB0E3E457EAC","rank":"normal","references":[{"hash":"3d81c19914d39cfc6f199d47a4561d9223e77a21","snaks":{"P248":[{"snaktype":"value","property":"P248","hash":"914657d833710b40c2c7d01062bc54606ee7f5a3","datavalue":{"value":{"entity-type":"item","numeric-id":58328557,"id":"Q58328557"},"type":"wikibase-entityid"},"datatype":"wikibase-item"}]},"snaks-order":["P248"]}]}],"P59":[{"mainsnak":{"snaktype":"value","property":"P59","hash":"7889804f26732f1f89461dcd260c61bce023d629","datavalue":{"value":{"entity-type":"item","numeric-id":9253,"id":"Q9253"},"type":"wikibase-entityid"},"datatype":"wikibase-item"},"type":"statement","id":"Q85670252$06054760-D12C-40C3-9F8C-8700F452A1D1","rank":"normal"}],"P6257":[{"mainsnak":{"snaktype":"value","property":"P6257","hash":"ca766c67460944425578fcbe2ee72177f0423c11","datavalue":{"value":{"amount":"+258.88894320568510","unit":"http://www.wikidata.org/entity/Q28390"},"type":"quantity"},"datatype":"quantity"},"type":"statement","id":"Q85670252$0F653F85-5E4D-401F-B73C-A2B07735EDE2","rank":"normal","references":[{"hash":"b64af6c056b6c5f6a7ea17156dcd718d4744bbf8","snaks":{"P248":[{"snaktype":"value","property":"P248","hash":"d17c7381d33a52742a63941e02c4babc38800c67","datavalue":{"value":{"entity-type":"item","numeric-id":51905050,"id":"Q51905050"},"type":"wikibase-entityid"},"datatype":"wikibase-item"}]},"snaks-order":["P248"]}]}],"P2215":[{"mainsnak":{"snaktype":"value","property":"P2215","hash":"ed7900ec9384767b293f76871ab98b5e0a117066","datavalue":{"value":{"amount":"-4.698","unit":"http://www.wikidata.org/entity/Q22137107","upperBound":"-4.547","lowerBound":"-4.849"},"type":"quantity"},"datatype":"quantity"},"type":"statement","qualifiers":{"P642":[{"snaktype":"value","property":"P642","hash":"77dfaa1e158068c266117826ae043bc387cf9e1b","datavalue":{"value":{"entity-type":"item","numeric-id":76287,"id":"Q76287"},"type":"wikibase-entityid"},"datatype":"wikibase-item"}]},"qualifiers-order":["P642"],"id":"Q85670252$9F6479A0-3321-4465-91E5-598820198F7D","rank":"normal","references":[{"hash":"b64af6c056b6c5f6a7ea17156dcd718d4744bbf8","snaks":{"P248":[{"snaktype":"value","property":"P248","hash":"d17c7381d33a52742a63941e02c4babc38800c67","datavalue":{"value":{"entity-type":"item","numeric-id":51905050,"id":"Q51905050"},"type":"wikibase-entityid"},"datatype":"wikibase-item"}]},"snaks-order":["P248"]}]},{"mainsnak":{"snaktype":"value","property":"P2215","hash":"764377a89eae56102e8a5dc988f41f33c99c280a","datavalue":{"value":{"amount":"-4.803","unit":"http://www.wikidata.org/entity/Q22137107","upperBound":"-4.647","lowerBound":"-4.959"},"type":"quantity"},"datatype":"quantity"},"type":"statement","qualifiers":{"P642":[{"snaktype":"value","property":"P642","hash":"934e52efd8d759eaa629af66469a07925ad54a01","datavalue":{"value":{"entity-type":"item","numeric-id":13442,"id":"Q13442"},"type":"wikibase-entityid"},"datatype":"wikibase-item"}]},"qualifiers-order":["P642"],"id":"Q85670252$107BC71C-34BA-48C4-9D39-737370CF2B1F","rank":"normal","references":[{"hash":"b64af6c056b6c5f6a7ea17156dcd718d4744bbf8","snaks":{"P248":[{"snaktype":"value","property":"P248","hash":"d17c7381d33a52742a63941e02c4babc38800c67","datavalue":{"value":{"entity-type":"item","numeric-id":51905050,"id":"Q51905050"},"type":"wikibase-entityid"},"datatype":"wikibase-item"}]},"snaks-order":["P248"]}]}],"P6258":[{"mainsnak":{"snaktype":"value","property":"P6258","hash":"d5e47217ca860508c3a76fffd669ada38eac3c02","datavalue":{"value":{"amount":"-57.08759272838490","unit":"http://www.wikidata.org/entity/Q28390"},"type":"quantity"},"datatype":"quantity"},"type":"statement","id":"Q85670252$5DF36E9C-9BD3-4DA9-9921-8CF4A43D3A60","rank":"normal","references":[{"hash":"b64af6c056b6c5f6a7ea17156dcd718d4744bbf8","snaks":{"P248":[{"snaktype":"value","property":"P248","hash":"d17c7381d33a52742a63941e02c4babc38800c67","datavalue":{"value":{"entity-type":"item","numeric-id":51905050,"id":"Q51905050"},"type":"wikibase-entityid"},"datatype":"wikibase-item"}]},"snaks-order":["P248"]}]}],"P2583":[{"mainsnak":{"snaktype":"value","property":"P2583","hash":"e695a712935cf983930a3deb1f5e68f22f657fe3","datavalue":{"value":{"amount":"+4905.64","unit":"http://www.wikidata.org/entity/Q12129","upperBound":"+5142.18","lowerBound":"+4669.10"},"type":"quantity"},"datatype":"quantity"},"type":"statement","id":"Q85670252$BD147611-3DAA-422F-92AA-7367F74386BD","rank":"normal","references":[{"hash":"1817971b301fa19d19b263c2789ca1da375a826e","snaks":{"P248":[{"snaktype":"value","property":"P248","hash":"23a5ccc229869ab13079895f56861a4eb6f92da4","datavalue":{"value":{"entity-type":"item","numeric-id":56915793,"id":"Q56915793"},"type":"wikibase-entityid"},"datatype":"wikibase-item"}]},"snaks-order":["P248"]}]}],"P7015":[{"mainsnak":{"snaktype":"value","property":"P7015","hash":"f63013ef795e599fcea5c3acb94c50dba429d1a4","datavalue":{"value":{"amount":"+9","unit":"http://www.wikidata.org/entity/Q39699418"},"type":"quantity"},"datatype":"quantity"},"type":"statement","id":"Q85670252$0290F9C8-02C0-4504-9834-75B9E411E871","rank":"normal","references":[{"hash":"3d81c19914d39cfc6f199d47a4561d9223e77a21","snaks":{"P248":[{"snaktype":"value","property":"P248","hash":"914657d833710b40c2c7d01062bc54606ee7f5a3","datavalue":{"value":{"entity-type":"item","numeric-id":58328557,"id":"Q58328557"},"type":"wikibase-entityid"},"datatype":"wikibase-item"}]},"snaks-order":["P248"]}]}],"P3083":[{"mainsnak":{"snaktype":"value","property":"P3083","hash":"6e71cd7ad33784745b14ce7c547f4e929581473d","datavalue":{"value":"V* DE Ara","type":"string"},"datatype":"external-id"},"type":"statement","id":"Q85670252$04D5F88A-6774-449C-AD24-4AA727160159","rank":"normal"}],"P31":[{"mainsnak":{"snaktype":"value","property":"P31","hash":"227fce90a3f146ab4d3f322ddf2ee33808414f80","datavalue":{"value":{"entity-type":"item","numeric-id":744691,"id":"Q744691"},"type":"wikibase-entityid"},"datatype":"wikibase-item"},"type":"statement","id":"Q85670252$5C15762A-0398-4077-ACC6-8E86E9A6EC72","rank":"normal","references":[{"hash":"8ba559d5760a03bedaaacc3c347bbfe4981560bf","snaks":{"P248":[{"snaktype":"value","property":"P248","hash":"841e49b3de3de902c9097967877cb9ff42610752","datavalue":{"value":{"entity-type":"item","numeric-id":654724,"id":"Q654724"},"type":"wikibase-entityid"},"datatype":"wikibase-item"}]},"snaks-order":["P248"]}]},{"mainsnak":{"snaktype":"value","property":"P31","hash":"cf4d9e15ba1a5a84169227f249913be8a5802dbd","datavalue":{"value":{"entity-type":"item","numeric-id":1153690,"id":"Q1153690"},"type":"wikibase-entityid"},"datatype":"wikibase-item"},"type":"statement","id":"Q85670252$3A495A31-891C-43ED-8FAD-1AB6FC59CF10","rank":"deprecated","references":[{"hash":"8ba559d5760a03bedaaacc3c347bbfe4981560bf","snaks":{"P248":[{"snaktype":"value","property":"P248","hash":"841e49b3de3de902c9097967877cb9ff42610752","datavalue":{"value":{"entity-type":"item","numeric-id":654724,"id":"Q654724"},"type":"wikibase-entityid"},"datatype":"wikibase-item"}]},"snaks-order":["P248"]}]}],"P2214":[{"mainsnak":{"snaktype":"value","property":"P2214","hash":"6898968769e4fc3881de0ed537f9583a367ec668","datavalue":{"value":{"amount":"+0.1078","unit":"http://www.wikidata.org/entity/Q21500224","upperBound":"+0.2200","lowerBound":"-0.0044"},"type":"quantity"},"datatype":"quantity"},"type":"statement","id":"Q85670252$7EF97A8F-99B2-47CF-B1C7-B3104A8A0399","rank":"normal","references":[{"hash":"b64af6c056b6c5f6a7ea17156dcd718d4744bbf8","snaks":{"P248":[{"snaktype":"value","property":"P248","hash":"d17c7381d33a52742a63941e02c4babc38800c67","datavalue":{"value":{"entity-type":"item","numeric-id":51905050,"id":"Q51905050"},"type":"wikibase-entityid"},"datatype":"wikibase-item"}]},"snaks-order":["P248"]}]}],"P6259":[{"mainsnak":{"snaktype":"value","property":"P6259","hash":"d2f39bbfbd81abac3a15296d0303a591b039faae","datavalue":{"value":{"entity-type":"item","numeric-id":1264450,"id":"Q1264450"},"type":"wikibase-entityid"},"datatype":"wikibase-item"},"type":"statement","id":"Q85670252$AD95791E-8B56-469E-A6CE-D0D798BFF035","rank":"normal","references":[{"hash":"b64af6c056b6c5f6a7ea17156dcd718d4744bbf8","snaks":{"P248":[{"snaktype":"value","property":"P248","hash":"d17c7381d33a52742a63941e02c4babc38800c67","datavalue":{"value":{"entity-type":"item","numeric-id":51905050,"id":"Q51905050"},"type":"wikibase-entityid"},"datatype":"wikibase-item"}]},"snaks-order":["P248"]}]}],"P1215":[{"mainsnak":{"snaktype":"value","property":"P1215","hash":"68bd46a3b1ee1621448cfebe4f3c6a9f314e6a11","datavalue":{"value":{"amount":"+10.46","unit":"1"},"type":"quantity"},"datatype":"quantity"},"type":"statement","qualifiers":{"P1227":[{"snaktype":"value","property":"P1227","hash":"6d021535513a30690a4075691163d7dd604ccaca","datavalue":{"value":{"entity-type":"item","numeric-id":15987557,"id":"Q15987557"},"type":"wikibase-entityid"},"datatype":"wikibase-item"}]},"qualifiers-order":["P1227"],"id":"Q85670252$BD10E7F0-8502-448B-AD4D-F451815818E5","rank":"normal","references":[{"hash":"221380bbe3481a43235282a275b47ec60cf42e03","snaks":{"P248":[{"snaktype":"value","property":"P248","hash":"426249303a30c5c40946d21d957f6c7c88ef97e3","datavalue":{"value":{"entity-type":"item","numeric-id":66649410,"id":"Q66649410"},"type":"wikibase-entityid"},"datatype":"wikibase-item"}]},"snaks-order":["P248"]}]},{"mainsnak":{"snaktype":"value","property":"P1215","hash":"1fe415af6567fd2721ea4a327c2c2737cdf89996","datavalue":{"value":{"amount":"+8.603","unit":"1","upperBound":"+8.626","lowerBound":"+8.580"},"type":"quantity"},"datatype":"quantity"},"type":"statement","qualifiers":{"P1227":[{"snaktype":"value","property":"P1227","hash":"b7d99518339690939386d75c2bb152f87e73cac5","datavalue":{"value":{"entity-type":"item","numeric-id":15991308,"id":"Q15991308"},"type":"wikibase-entityid"},"datatype":"wikibase-item"}]},"qualifiers-order":["P1227"],"id":"Q85670252$E6A2A464-76FC-4F89-8431-5E359E77F1B9","rank":"normal","references":[{"hash":"6b647975ae22e206a4cd711623ecb06abadbdb9e","snaks":{"P248":[{"snaktype":"value","property":"P248","hash":"40842ef468cb1e142b8b47c1fb6e3779978c000c","datavalue":{"value":{"entity-type":"item","numeric-id":66309067,"id":"Q66309067"},"type":"wikibase-entityid"},"datatype":"wikibase-item"}]},"snaks-order":["P248"]}]},{"mainsnak":{"snaktype":"value","property":"P1215","hash":"9af902af6e730bbdb6d65898c5d03c97156bc401","datavalue":{"value":{"amount":"+7.750","unit":"1","upperBound":"+7.777","lowerBound":"+7.723"},"type":"quantity"},"datatype":"quantity"},"type":"statement","qualifiers":{"P1227":[{"snaktype":"value","property":"P1227","hash":"3c30b45b4f89abb0a4026fd0688c4c1227d38837","datavalue":{"value":{"entity-type":"item","numeric-id":16556693,"id":"Q16556693"},"type":"wikibase-entityid"},"datatype":"wikibase-item"}]},"qualifiers-order":["P1227"],"id":"Q85670252$52A5B95C-08EB-418F-BFD3-2616673A0990","rank":"normal","references":[{"hash":"6b647975ae22e206a4cd711623ecb06abadbdb9e","snaks":{"P248":[{"snaktype":"value","property":"P248","hash":"40842ef468cb1e142b8b47c1fb6e3779978c000c","datavalue":{"value":{"entity-type":"item","numeric-id":66309067,"id":"Q66309067"},"type":"wikibase-entityid"},"datatype":"wikibase-item"}]},"snaks-order":["P248"]}]},{"mainsnak":{"snaktype":"value","property":"P1215","hash":"a11490b2e65949bad75d75e53c4fde50029423ec","datavalue":{"value":{"amount":"+7.241","unit":"1","upperBound":"+7.267","lowerBound":"+7.215"},"type":"quantity"},"datatype":"quantity"},"type":"statement","qualifiers":{"P1227":[{"snaktype":"value","property":"P1227","hash":"c55a66d6326fb5f8cd17a333e364d011c5679619","datavalue":{"value":{"entity-type":"item","numeric-id":2520419,"id":"Q2520419"},"type":"wikibase-entityid"},"datatype":"wikibase-item"}]},"qualifiers-order":["P1227"],"id":"Q85670252$D02C2AF4-2281-4165-968C-D213718E5FC4","rank":"normal","references":[{"hash":"6b647975ae22e206a4cd711623ecb06abadbdb9e","snaks":{"P248":[{"snaktype":"value","property":"P248","hash":"40842ef468cb1e142b8b47c1fb6e3779978c000c","datavalue":{"value":{"entity-type":"item","numeric-id":66309067,"id":"Q66309067"},"type":"wikibase-entityid"},"datatype":"wikibase-item"}]},"snaks-order":["P248"]}]},{"mainsnak":{"snaktype":"value","property":"P1215","hash":"f068d0f49440f97108bb389ec9082f1d2c064604","datavalue":{"value":{"amount":"+12.6565","unit":"1","upperBound":"+12.6990","lowerBound":"+12.6140"},"type":"quantity"},"datatype":"quantity"},"type":"statement","qualifiers":{"P1227":[{"snaktype":"value","property":"P1227","hash":"432d061d3e64f750fc2df080c02cbcd281183dbf","datavalue":{"value":{"entity-type":"item","numeric-id":66659648,"id":"Q66659648"},"type":"wikibase-entityid"},"datatype":"wikibase-item"}]},"qualifiers-order":["P1227"],"id":"Q85670252$3A809A48-C8CA-4ED3-875E-605F092330EB","rank":"normal","references":[{"hash":"b64af6c056b6c5f6a7ea17156dcd718d4744bbf8","snaks":{"P248":[{"snaktype":"value","property":"P248","hash":"d17c7381d33a52742a63941e02c4babc38800c67","datavalue":{"value":{"entity-type":"item","numeric-id":51905050,"id":"Q51905050"},"type":"wikibase-entityid"},"datatype":"wikibase-item"}]},"snaks-order":["P248"]}]}],"P528":[{"mainsnak":{"snaktype":"value","property":"P528","hash":"0bdf6efa0d0996363f4ea0a7c295a53a06f5a4f4","datavalue":{"value":"SV* HV 6719","type":"string"},"datatype":"string"},"type":"statement","id":"Q85670252$A0BE5C05-BD6F-4A77-940F-E983A433F2CE","rank":"normal","references":[{"hash":"8ba559d5760a03bedaaacc3c347bbfe4981560bf","snaks":{"P248":[{"snaktype":"value","property":"P248","hash":"841e49b3de3de902c9097967877cb9ff42610752","datavalue":{"value":{"entity-type":"item","numeric-id":654724,"id":"Q654724"},"type":"wikibase-entityid"},"datatype":"wikibase-item"}]},"snaks-order":["P248"]}]},{"mainsnak":{"snaktype":"value","property":"P528","hash":"314852a5a2ab798bbf29742287b3e2f97e32ae09","datavalue":{"value":"V* DE Ara","type":"string"},"datatype":"string"},"type":"statement","id":"Q85670252$C3222326-D6DD-428B-B7B9-0D5C5DD6D672","rank":"normal","references":[{"hash":"8ba559d5760a03bedaaacc3c347bbfe4981560bf","snaks":{"P248":[{"snaktype":"value","property":"P248","hash":"841e49b3de3de902c9097967877cb9ff42610752","datavalue":{"value":{"entity-type":"item","numeric-id":654724,"id":"Q654724"},"type":"wikibase-entityid"},"datatype":"wikibase-item"}]},"snaks-order":["P248"]}]},{"mainsnak":{"snaktype":"value","property":"P528","hash":"b91ef90a761b4312d9282beaf755de491c51adda","datavalue":{"value":"2MASS J17153336-5705152","type":"string"},"datatype":"string"},"type":"statement","qualifiers":{"P972":[{"snaktype":"value","property":"P972","hash":"11d053f649ebac851056740fd904fa57f8c43719","datavalue":{"value":{"entity-type":"item","numeric-id":1454942,"id":"Q1454942"},"type":"wikibase-entityid"},"datatype":"wikibase-item"}]},"qualifiers-order":["P972"],"id":"Q85670252$F621D4A5-1747-4867-A815-8FC851298F7B","rank":"normal","references":[{"hash":"8ba559d5760a03bedaaacc3c347bbfe4981560bf","snaks":{"P248":[{"snaktype":"value","property":"P248","hash":"841e49b3de3de902c9097967877cb9ff42610752","datavalue":{"value":{"entity-type":"item","numeric-id":654724,"id":"Q654724"},"type":"wikibase-entityid"},"datatype":"wikibase-item"}]},"snaks-order":["P248"]}]},{"mainsnak":{"snaktype":"value","property":"P528","hash":"07022c11012e5c56235ac4ef70324a4084da208c","datavalue":{"value":"UNSW-V 295","type":"string"},"datatype":"string"},"type":"statement","id":"Q85670252$462DC8A9-6234-4F91-AB36-ECF4DFF44865","rank":"normal","references":[{"hash":"8ba559d5760a03bedaaacc3c347bbfe4981560bf","snaks":{"P248":[{"snaktype":"value","property":"P248","hash":"841e49b3de3de902c9097967877cb9ff42610752","datavalue":{"value":{"entity-type":"item","numeric-id":654724,"id":"Q654724"},"type":"wikibase-entityid"},"datatype":"wikibase-item"}]},"snaks-order":["P248"]}]},{"mainsnak":{"snaktype":"value","property":"P528","hash":"9d4c6281bc2cd893492b47b455a7a87a9dc7c1a9","datavalue":{"value":"RAVE J171533.4-570515","type":"string"},"datatype":"string"},"type":"statement","qualifiers":{"P972":[{"snaktype":"value","property":"P972","hash":"64b950040f43fa44494cca0b58a193494cdaf23a","datavalue":{"value":{"entity-type":"item","numeric-id":1414921,"id":"Q1414921"},"type":"wikibase-entityid"},"datatype":"wikibase-item"}]},"qualifiers-order":["P972"],"id":"Q85670252$611F6BB6-3950-479F-AFB8-BE79E4DA1584","rank":"normal","references":[{"hash":"8ba559d5760a03bedaaacc3c347bbfe4981560bf","snaks":{"P248":[{"snaktype":"value","property":"P248","hash":"841e49b3de3de902c9097967877cb9ff42610752","datavalue":{"value":{"entity-type":"item","numeric-id":654724,"id":"Q654724"},"type":"wikibase-entityid"},"datatype":"wikibase-item"}]},"snaks-order":["P248"]}]},{"mainsnak":{"snaktype":"value","property":"P528","hash":"3ab4c8f39bdece84953ee4e299c1b6d0f77da324","datavalue":{"value":"Gaia DR2 5916392255706298752","type":"string"},"datatype":"string"},"type":"statement","qualifiers":{"P972":[{"snaktype":"value","property":"P972","hash":"f94f9c2a2010b40347a3cd5eb8a508ec9314a043","datavalue":{"value":{"entity-type":"item","numeric-id":51905050,"id":"Q51905050"},"type":"wikibase-entityid"},"datatype":"wikibase-item"}]},"qualifiers-order":["P972"],"id":"Q85670252$66932D63-C152-4CE8-9C8F-7D7D84F5EA5F","rank":"normal","references":[{"hash":"8ba559d5760a03bedaaacc3c347bbfe4981560bf","snaks":{"P248":[{"snaktype":"value","property":"P248","hash":"841e49b3de3de902c9097967877cb9ff42610752","datavalue":{"value":{"entity-type":"item","numeric-id":654724,"id":"Q654724"},"type":"wikibase-entityid"},"datatype":"wikibase-item"}]},"snaks-order":["P248"]}]},{"mainsnak":{"snaktype":"value","property":"P528","hash":"7efef3c6dfff1a3394fd94bf2cad24058375057a","datavalue":{"value":"DE Ara","type":"string"},"datatype":"string"},"type":"statement","qualifiers":{"P972":[{"snaktype":"value","property":"P972","hash":"c5a4f912362921c7a08383c59d0916f458c51b01","datavalue":{"value":{"entity-type":"item","numeric-id":222662,"id":"Q222662"},"type":"wikibase-entityid"},"datatype":"wikibase-item"}]},"qualifiers-order":["P972"],"id":"Q85670252$2B26F076-925A-4802-A2E0-E79F53A76433","rank":"normal"}],"P2216":[{"mainsnak":{"snaktype":"value","property":"P2216","hash":"9501c4d02002b8e5bf0af266952a242399975d04","datavalue":{"value":{"amount":"-69.054","unit":"http://www.wikidata.org/entity/Q3674704","upperBound":"-60.055","lowerBound":"-78.053"},"type":"quantity"},"datatype":"quantity"},"type":"statement","id":"Q85670252$2B2C64FE-7AE0-43C2-9C98-8D1A88B989B5","rank":"deprecated","references":[{"hash":"3d81c19914d39cfc6f199d47a4561d9223e77a21","snaks":{"P248":[{"snaktype":"value","property":"P248","hash":"914657d833710b40c2c7d01062bc54606ee7f5a3","datavalue":{"value":{"entity-type":"item","numeric-id":58328557,"id":"Q58328557"},"type":"wikibase-entityid"},"datatype":"wikibase-item"}]},"snaks-order":["P248"]}]},{"mainsnak":{"snaktype":"value","property":"P2216","hash":"bffd1614ebe5fe35e754a154fb5bb6da1002b710","datavalue":{"value":{"amount":"-69.05","unit":"http://www.wikidata.org/entity/Q3674704","upperBound":"-60.05","lowerBound":"-78.05"},"type":"quantity"},"datatype":"quantity"},"type":"statement","id":"Q85670252$E7B318B1-C37D-4B41-82D6-859EF9FBF9F8","rank":"normal","references":[{"hash":"1817971b301fa19d19b263c2789ca1da375a826e","snaks":{"P248":[{"snaktype":"value","property":"P248","hash":"23a5ccc229869ab13079895f56861a4eb6f92da4","datavalue":{"value":{"entity-type":"item","numeric-id":56915793,"id":"Q56915793"},"type":"wikibase-entityid"},"datatype":"wikibase-item"}]},"snaks-order":["P248"]}]}]},"sitelinks":{}}},"success":1}
```

The property I was looking for is "instance of" (P31). But the value "Mira variable" does not appear in the result.

```
To access:
https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Q85670252

Statements:
     - instance of (P31) :   Mira variable
```

Does anyone know how to achieve this?

Comment: what do you mean by does not appear? `Q744691` does appear in the returned JSON. Indeed, a human readable label does not given that this belongs to the other entity. One way would be to do another call for the class entity.

Comment: Indeed, the more powerful way would be to use SPARQL, e.g. `SELECT ?item ?itemLabel ?itemDescription ?itemAltLabel ?prop ?propertyLabel ?propertyValue ?propertyValueLabel ?qualifier ?qualifierLabel ?qualifierValue 
        { 
VALUES (?item) {(wd:Q85670252)}
?item ?prop ?statement . 
?statement ?ps ?propertyValue . 
 ?property wikibase:claim ?prop . 
            ?property wikibase:statementProperty ?ps . 
            OPTIONAL { ?statement ?pq ?qualifierValue . ?qualifier wikibase:qualifier ?pq . } 
            SERVICE wikibase:label { bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "en" } 
}`

Comment: You can try the query [here](https://w.wiki/U$s)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the haswbstatement keyword to filter by property. The following call searches for all items with the property instance of (P31) set to Mira variable (Q744691):

https://www.wikidata.org/w/api.php?action=query&list=search&srsearch=haswbstatement:P31=Q744691

An alternative would be to use SPARQL but this would be slower and might not reflect changes in Wikidata until hours later:

```
SELECT ?item WHERE {
  ?item wdt:P31 wd:Q744691.
}
```

[The query above in the Wikidata SPARQL editor.](https://w.wiki/VQR)

Comment: How can I use `haswbstatement` if I want to have all results? It seems to limit itself to a certain number. Is it really faster than SPARQL for some demanding queries, such as getting all instances of humans?